# Installation of GrowingSOM in R

Tags: r, package, failed-installation

I am trying to install GrowingSOM package in R by following instructions from https://github.com/alexhunziker/GrowingSOM#readme

Could anyone tells what wrong of the followings steps?

1. download code.
2. `install.packages("plotrix")`
3. install.packages(repos=NULL, "PATH_TO_HERE\GrowingSOM_VERSION.zip", type="binary")
   I used my own path and found that the zip code is called "GrowingSOM-master.zip" but not "GrowingSOM_VERSION.zip". So I changed the code as `install.packages(repos=NULL, "C:\\Users\\Downloads\\GrowingSOM-master.zip", type="binary")`

However, no installation done.

Comment: I don't see a zipped file for downloading. Why aren't you using the first method?

Comment: @IRTFM, if not downloading a zipped file, just install.packages("GrowingSOM"). RStudio said "Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘GrowingSOM’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages"

Comment: If you set repos=NULL, the function looks for a local version of the package. If you have tools for compilation properly installed, it's possible that you could use `remotes::install_github`.

Comment: Thanks @IRTFM. Sorry that I am new to R and still do not quite understand what to do after installing "plotrix". Do you mind writing down the code for installing GrowingSOM? Much appreciated!!

Comment: I cannot tell whether you have the toolbox to compile C code. (I'm guessing that you do not.)

Comment: @ IRTFM, you are referring Rtools, I did installed. rtools42-5253-5107-signed

Comment: So did you try `install_github`?